# thanos query how to connect a TLS endpoint and a noTLS endpoint at the same time

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, thanos

thanos query support to specify multi endpoints, like

```
- --store=dnssrv+_grpc._tcp.prometheus-operated
- --store=192.168.1.1:443
```

I can set `grpc-client-*` flags to connect `192.168.1.1:443`, but I can't connect the `prometheus-operated` service.

Does the thanos query support connecting to a TLS endpoint and a noTLS endpoint at the same time?

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you meant this to be "Than**o**s query"?

Comment: yes, thanks query, do you have any idea?